# Broadcast video sound on airplay VLC

Tags: mac, vlc-media-player, airplay

I would like to broadcast my video sound on my IHome device with airplay and watch video on my mac book.
It is possible to do that ?

I know you can broadcast music with airplay, broadcast full video on apple tv but I can't found any information about just broadcast video sound.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. What exact equipment and software do you have, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I give you a bad explanation. I have a mac book pro. I read my video on VLC and I have a airplay speaker for the sound. I want to watch my video on my mac book pro with VLC and I want VLC to broadcast the sound with airplay on my speaker.

Comment: Ah. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Do you know another software to do that ? I don't understand why I can't found this feature. It's a basic feature for me.